# Emulator doesn't show any picture. SurfaceView Android

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I saw this one from here. And I just want to try if it is working. 
Link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/03/android-http-camera-live-preview.html

This is the first class called MyCamAppActivity.java

```
    package com.javacodegeeks.android.camera;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;    
    import android.view.Window;  
public class MyCamAppActivity extends Activity {         
    private SurfaceView cameraPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this);

        setContentView(cameraPreview);
    }           
     }
```

And this is the 2nd class called the CameraPreview

```
    package com.javacodegeeks.android.camera;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Camera camera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder2, int format, int w, int h) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder1) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder1);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception surfaceCreated()", "e=" + e);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
          }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

}
```

As far as I know, when you use surfaceview in android programming it automatically generated the picture on your screen. But in my case, it's just plain black picture. Btw, the complete package in the site doesn't have any .xml contents in it. So, I don't know if I still have to fix something in the xml. Hope someone or any of you could help me ASAP.